# Geometrically proving the half-angle formula for sine from a particular diagram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I have attached a picture of the diagram I am using to prove the trig identity $\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})= \sqrt{(\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{2})}$. I have that $\sin \alpha = \frac{DG}{OD}$ and $\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{DE}{OD}$ as well as $\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{EF}{OE}=EF$. I'm unsure of what segment could even represent $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{2})}$?

Comment: https://www.themathpage.com/atrig/sum-proof.htm

Comment: Formatting tip:  Type `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$` to obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x $, and $\cot x$, respectively.

Comment: You may improve your question by generalizing it to (unequal) angles DOE & EOF (by letting them to be α & β respectively), and do the same thing with this question.  Then you easily get a compound angle formula, whose special case is the half angle formula.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 although that may improve my question, that is not my question. I want to know how to take these two $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ angles and solve for the identity.

Comment: Your question is just a special case of the above question.  Btw, your last prompt contains a typo.

Comment: The quantity under the radical in the diagram and in the question as stated do not match. I suspect the diagram is asking to prove a version of the half-angle formula $\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1-\cos \theta}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Construct $DF$
let $DF$ intersect $OE$ at $P$

$\triangle OPF \cong \triangle OPD$
$\angle OPD\cong \angle OPF$ is a right angle.

$\sin \frac a2 = \frac {\text {opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac {PF}{OF} = \frac {PD}{OD}$

$OF = OD = \cos \frac a2\\
DP = PF = \cos \frac a2\sin \frac a2$

$DF= DP + PF =  2\cos \frac a2\sin \frac a2$

by the Pythagorean theorem $DF^2 = FG^2 + GD^2$

$OF = \cos \frac a2\\OG = OD\sin a= \cos \frac a2 \cos a\\FG = OF - OG = \cos a2 (1-cos a)\\GD = OD\sin a = \cos \frac a2\sin a$

$(2\cos \frac a2\sin \frac a2)^2 = (\cos \frac a2)^2(1-\cos a)^2 + ((\cos \frac a2)^2(\sin a)^2$

We can divide through by $(\cos \frac a2)^2$

$(2\sin \frac a2)^2 = (1-\cos a)^2 + (\sin a)^2$

$4\sin^2 \frac a2 = 1-2\cos a + cos^2 a + \sin^2 a = 2-2\cos a\\
\sin \frac a2 =  \sqrt {\frac{1-\cos a}{2}}$

Comment: I want to use the diagram in the picture above. It is very similar but I do not see how I could conclude the $2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$ as you have here.Any ideas?

Comment: Add the line $DF$  And lets say $DF$ intersects  $OE$ at $P$ then $\triangle OFP\cong \triangle ODP$ and $\frac {OF}{OP} = \sin \frac a2$

Comment: how can you conclude $\frac{OF}{OP}=\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$? $OF=\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and we made up FP. We know $EF=\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$ though. And as I look further ahead, you set up the Pythagorean Theorem saying $OP=1-\cos\alpha$ but how can we conclude that $PE=\cos\alpha$?

Comment: Adjacent is OP which is $1-PE$.

Comment: @KMath sorry $\sin \frac a2 = \frac {\text {opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$

Comment: that would be $\frac{\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}{\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}}$? So $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

As "trigonographs" go, this one seems unsatisfying. Maybe I'm missing a cool geometric trick, but I don't see a way to tease-out the half-angle formulas from the elements given, without invoking a double-angle formula. Ideally, trigonographs are more self-evident.

---

Here's a version of the diagram that I've "unfolded" a bit to reduce some overlap, replacing $\triangle DEH$ with $\triangle DEH^\prime$ and $\triangle ODG$ with $\triangle ODG^\prime$. Also, to avoid fractions, I'm using $\theta$ and $2\theta$ instead of $\alpha/2$ and $\alpha$. Side-lengths flow readly from $1$ to the rest of the figure.

[image]

Here, it's clear that
$$\sin\theta\sin 2\theta = \cos\theta - \cos\theta \cos 2\theta \tag{1}$$
Then, since we "know" that $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, we can write
$$\sin\theta \cdot 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \cos\theta\;\left(\;1-\cos 2\theta\;\right) \quad\to\quad \sin^2\theta = \frac12 \left(\;1-\cos 2\theta\;\right) \tag{2}$$

We also have
$$\begin{align}
\cos\theta\sin 2\theta = \sin\theta + \sin\theta \cos 2\theta &\quad\to\quad
\cos\theta\cdot 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \sin\theta\left(\;1+\cos 2\theta\;\right) \\[4pt]
&\quad\to\quad \cos^2\theta = \frac12\left(\;1+\cos 2\theta\;\right)
\end{align} \tag{3}$$

We get to the desired formula(s), but not so tidily as one might hope. I wonder: Does the source have a derivation that doesn't require re-writing $\sin 2\theta$?

---

It's worth comparing the above to another trigonograph:

[image]

Here, a couple of leg-over-hypotenuse proportions from pairs of similar right triangles give well-known geometric mean relations:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2\sin\theta}{2} = \frac{1-\cos 2\theta}{2\sin\theta} &\quad\to\quad \sin^2\theta = \frac12\left(\;1-\cos 2\theta\;\right) \\[12pt]
\frac{2\cos\theta}{2} = \frac{1+\cos 2\theta}{2\cos\theta} &\quad\to\quad \cos^2\theta = \frac12\left(\;1+\cos 2\theta\;\right)
\end{align} \tag{4}$$

No extra trig identities are required, which would seem to give this trigonograph something of an intuitive advantage over the figure in the question.