# Trigonometric Books/ self-learning

Tags: trigonometry, self-learning, book-recommendation

Good morning, I currently starting my journey to study mathematics more seriously. I'd like to focus now in trigonometry. I know just about all the trigonometric identities half angle, double angles, sum difference, inverse-functions, Pythagorean and such. I however, want a book that does not teach me how to compute (which I know). I'd love a book with geometric interpretations and proofs as well as algebraic.

For example:

What does it mean to have sin($3\theta$)... Do I have three triangles?...

what does it mean to have sin($\theta/2$)...Do I cut my triangle in half?...

What is the proof for summation of double or even triple angles! how does it make geometric sense... where is its proof...

etc..

I only want theory with the intuition behind things. Unfortunately when I try to search up books for trigonometry they only focus on blindly applying a property that they don't fully define.

Thank you for any tips and ideas.

Comment: Congrats on taking the journey, man. I quit my job 1 year ago to go back to school for computer science and do something similar. It has been an awesome ride thus far. I don't know of any trig book recommendations though.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Mathematics really is amazing when you understand the concepts. Thank you for your support.

Comment: You may use a circle to proof $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: Agreed. Do you have a particular goal in mind or is it for the love of the sport?

Comment: Love of the sport. I just want to understand mathematics @RyRytheFlyGuy

Comment: I have a few geometric proofs (what I call "trigonographs") posted here. For instance, [Angle Sum and Difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409), [Triple Angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/852230/409), [Half-angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2981511/409).  See also my [Trigonography site](http://trigonography.com). I aspire to roll all of this stuff into a book; so far, I have this drafty document ["(Almost) Everything You Need to Remember about Trigonometry, in One Simple Diagram"](http://tricochet.com/math/pdfs/AlmostEverythingAboutTrig.pdf) covering some fundamentals

Comment: @Blue It looks amazing. I'll go over it thoroughly  tonight. Currently at my job. Thank you!

Comment: Check out [Trigonometric Delights](https://www.amazon.com/Trigonometric-Delights-Eli-Maor/dp/0691095418).

Comment: @g.kov sounds delightful! thank you. I'll look into it

Comment: I didn't find a better one than https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs/page/182